# Data APIs/feeds available as packages in R

Tags: r, references, dataset

EDIT: The [Web Technologies and Services](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/WebTechnologies.html) CRAN [task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) contains a much more comprehensive list of data sources and APIs available in R.  You can [submit a pull request on github](https://github.com/ropensci/webservices) if you wish to add a package to the task view.

---

I'm making a list of the various data feeds that are already hooked into R or that are easy to setup. Here's my initial list of packages, and I was wondering what else I'm missing.

I'm trying to limit this list to "real time" or "close to real time" data feeds/APIs, where the underlying data might change between downloads.  There's plenty of [lists out there](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) for static datasets, which only require one download.

This list is currently biased towards financial/time series data, and I could use some help expanding it into other domains.

Free Data:
Data Source -  Package
[Google Finance historical data](http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:MSFT) - [quantmod](http://www.quantmod.com/)
[Google Finance balance sheets](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:MSFT&fstype=ii) - quantmod
[Yahoo Finance historical data](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=MSFT%20Historical%20Prices) - quantmod
Yahoo Finance historical data - [tseries](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/tseries/html/get.hist.quote.html)
[Yahoo Finance current options chain](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=MSFT) - quantmod
[Yahoo Finance historical analyst estimates](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ud?s=MSFT) - [fImport](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fImport/index.html)
[Yahoo Finance current key stats](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=MSFT) - fImport - seems to be broken
[OANDA historic exchange rates/metal prices](http://www.oanda.com/) - quantmod
[FRED historic macroeconomic indicators](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/) - quantmod
[World Bank historic  macroeconomic indicators](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator) - [WDI](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WDI/index.html)
[Google Trends historic search volume data](http://www.google.com/trends?q=microsoft) - [RGoogleTrends](http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleTrends/)
Google Docs - [RGoogleDocs](http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleDocs/)
Google Storage - [RGoogleStorage](http://www.omegahat.org/RGoogleStorage/)
[Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/search/microsoft) - [twitteR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/index.html)
[Zillow](http://www.zillow.com/) - [Zillow](http://www.omegahat.org/Zillow/)
[New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/) - [RNYTimes](http://www.omegahat.org/RNYTimes/)
[US Census 2000](http://www.census.gov/main/www/cen2000.html) - [UScensus2000](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UScensus2000/index.html)
[infochimps](http://www.infochimps.com/) - [infochimps](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/infochimps/index.html)
[datamarket](http://datamarket.com/) - [rdatamarket](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rdatamarket/index.html) - requires free account
[Factual.com](http://www.factual.com/) - [factualR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/factualR/index.html)
Geocode addresses - [RDSTK](http://thelogcabin.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/r-and-the-data-science-toolkit/)
Map coordinates to political boundaries - RDSTK
[Weather Underground](http://www.wunderground.com/) - [Roll your own](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/991)
[Google News](http://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=NASDAQ:MSFT) - [Roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761576/improving-a-function-to-get-stock-news-data-from-google-in-r)
[Earth Sciences](http://opendap.deltares.nl/thredds/catalog/opendap/catalog.html) netCDF [Data](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/files.html) - [Roll your own](http://public.deltares.nl/display/OET/KML+overview+of+OPeNDAP+data#KMLoverviewofOPeNDAPdata-AccessingnetCDF/OPeNDAPdatawithR)
[Climate Data](http://processtrends.com/RClimate.htm) - [Roll your own](http://chartsgraphs.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/using-rclimate-to-retrieve-climate-series-data/)
Public health data - [Roll your own](http://www.medepi.net/msamuel/R.Visual.Display.Samuel.10-2008.pdf)
[OAI Harvester](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OAIHarvester/index.html) - Open Archives Initiative harvester
[RAmazonS3](http://www.omegahat.org/RAmazonS3/) -  S3 Amazon storage server
[Rflikr](http://www.omegahat.org/Rflickr/) - Flikr api

Requires a subscription:
[Bloomberg](http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/software_support/) - [RBloomberg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RBloomberg/index.html)
[LIM](http://www.lim.com/) - [LIM](http://www.lim.com/sites/default/files/R_package_LIMWS.pdf)
[Trades and Quotes from NYSE](http://www.nyxdata.com/Data-Products/Daily-TAQ) - [RTAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTAQ/index.html)
[Interactive Brokers](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/p.php?f=marketData) - [IBrokers](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IBrokers/index.html)

Comment: depends on what you mean by 'easy to set up'... I have a number of custom scripts that are 'easy to set up'

Comment: Right now I'm defining "easy to setup" as "the package exists" or "someone's posted/published a function to download the data"

Comment: I would further define "the packages exists" as "the package is on CRAN" or "the package is on R Forge," "the package is on some CRAN-like, public repository."

Comment: Addition: [Federal Register API](http://christophergandrud.blogspot.fr/2012/09/federal-register-apir-package-ideas.html) (in the works).

Comment: This thread may also be of interest: [Import stock price from Yahoo Finance into R](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8407/).

Comment: I'm using a lot MERRA data from the NASA http://gmao.gsfc.nasa.gov/research/merra/intro.php I don't know if there is an API but I wrote some code to do the scrapping of any variable in the past and still using it... should clean it some day to make a package

Comment: @robingirard If you do, add it to the [Web Technologies and services](https://github.com/ropensci/webservices) CRAN task view!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. [Instructions for using R to download netCDF data can be found here](http://public.deltares.nl/display/OET/KML+overview+of+OPeNDAP+data#KMLoverviewofOPeNDAPdata-AccessingnetCDF%2FOPeNDAPdatawithR), a common format used for storing Earth science data, e.g. as in marine geospatial data from [OpenEarth](http://opendap.deltares.nl/thredds/catalog/opendap/catalog.html) or climate model driver and forecasts from [UCAR](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/files.html)
2. [rnpn](https://github.com/SChamberlain/rnpn) (under development) enables you to get data from the National Phenology Network - a citizen science project to track the timing of plant green-up, flowering, and senescence. See the developer's [blog post](http://r-ecology.blogspot.com/2011/08/rnpn-r-interface-for-national-phenology.html).
3. -obsolete- [RClimate](http://processtrends.com/RClimate.htm) provides tools to download and manipulate flat-file climate data (with tutorials, including [here](http://chartsgraphs.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/using-rclimate-to-retrieve-climate-series-data/)-
4. Download historical finance data with [`tseries::get.hist.quote`](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/tseries/html/get.hist.quote.html)
5. Michael Samuel's documents [downloading public health data](http://www.medepi.net/msamuel/R.Visual.Display.Samuel.10-2008.pdf)
6. `raster::getData` provides access to climate variables via worldclim

Comment: What is "netCDF data?"

Comment: @Zach [NetCDF](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/) is a kind of universal structured way of storing large datasets. An alternative approach relies on the [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) format.

Comment: @David (+1) Many thanks for the fourth point!

Comment: What happend to RClimate? I cannot find the package anywhere

Comment: now there is a ncdf4 library on R to handle netcdf4. It is more complicated to install than ncdf but the later is deprecated I think. A few years ago I even managed to install netcdf4 with Min GW64 to make this package work on windows :) if I did it, it means it's feasible ... and it seems that D. Pierce (author of the package) is providing sources on his web site http://cirrus.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncdf/

Answer (score 8):

There's a project aimed at creating R packages with this objective (R interface to real-time APIs) called [rOpenSci](http://ropensci.org), which has [18 packages currently](https://github.com/ropensci) available or in development. Some (rnpn, rfishbase) are on your list already.

Great list!  and full disclosure - I'm part of the rOpenSci project.

Answer (score 1):

1. [ONETr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ONETr/index.html) - efficient interaction with the O*NET™ API, offering occupational descriptor data from the U.S. Department of Labor.